Can't run await with async methods in llama index
I try the code below which is from https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/examples/evaluation/batch_eval/.
I came across an error of

SyntaxError: 'await' outside function

from llama_index.core.evaluation import BatchEvalRunner

runner = BatchEvalRunner(
    {"faithfulness": faithfulness_gpt4, "relevancy": relevancy_gpt4},
    workers=8,
)

eval_results = await runner.aevaluate_queries(
    vector_index.as_query_engine(llm=llm), queries=qas.questions
)

I tried asyncio loop method as shown below but got another error:

RuntimeError: coroutine raised StopIteration

import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

eval_results = loop.run_until_complete(runner.aevaluate_queries(index.as_query_engine(), queries=eval_question_texts[:1]))
loop.close()

Any idea for sorting this out?
Thanks

Did you try using the sync function?

Who incorrectly marked this as alr answered? OP using await outside a coroutine is a symptom of the problem, which is StopIteration. To the OP: I feel like there's probably a missing use_async=True or streaming=True. I'm here because it would seem that VectorStoreIndex.from_documents requires nest_asyncio or low-level pipeline manipulation. Also, there's a fun warning about inconsistency in the API: https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/module_guides/deploying/chat_engines/usage_pattern/

You cannot call await outside of a coroutine. The only place you can is in a REPL and possibly a Jupyter notebook. In fact, it looks like the documentation that you linked may have been written with a Jupyter notebook and then exported to HTML, which explains why they have a bug in their documentation.
To fix the code that you posted and including the example in the linked posted, the following should ideally work:
from llama_index.core.evaluation import DatasetGenerator

dataset_generator = DatasetGenerator.from_documents(documents, llm=llm)

qas = dataset_generator.generate_dataset_from_nodes(num=3)

from llama_index.core.evaluation import BatchEvalRunner

runner = BatchEvalRunner(
    {"faithfulness": faithfulness_gpt4, "relevancy": relevancy_gpt4},
    workers=8,
)

async def evaluate_queries():
    await runner.aevaluate_queries(
        vector_index.as_query_engine(llm=llm), 
        queries=qas.questions
    )

eval_results = asyncio.run(evaluate_queries())

This puts the await inside a coroutine, and then it uses asyncio.run to run the coroutine as a task on an event loop and return the results.

Yes, I tried this too. But the error would become RuntimeError: coroutine raised StopIteration

You tried asyncio.run? Do you include the qas example code shown in the documentation that you linked? Because the code you posted depends upon it.

evaluate_queries doesn't return anything. eval_results will be None. And seems quite pointless to define an async function just to run another async function.

It doesn't matter what it returns. Whatever it returns will be bound to eval_results. And you don't have to define a coroutine just to run another coroutine. You can pass runner.aevaluate_queries(vector_index.as_query_engine(llm=llm), queries=qas.questions) directly to asyncio.run.

I still got the error of RuntimeError: coroutine raised StopIteration using asyncio.run

Then that's a problem with the library, not asyncio.
